# Rails method works in development but 500 internal server error in Heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using rails 4.1.8, ruby 2.1.1, heroku toolbelt 3.17.1
In rails I've written a method that returns random rows from the db (postgres) that meet certain parameters:

```
  elsif f == 'random'
    (Piece.all - current_user.followed_pieces - current_user.pieces).sample(10)
```

This method functions properly in development. In deployment, when this method is triggered Heroku returns a 500 internal server error with altogether unhelpful logs:

```
2014-12-08T18:28:22.628654+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/pieces?filter=random"
host=sheltered-castle-3185.herokuapp.com request_id=88107b5e-45f6-4d44-8c3c-9b91c18411f2   
fwd="67.174.254.226" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=90ms status=500 bytes=330
```

I've migrated the database and in production.rb my config.log_level = :debug, no other pages or methods on the webapp trigger a server error.

Comment: Is that really the only log message you see? Also, have you tried it locally with a full copy of the production database? Depending on how many `Piece`s there are, this could be a really inefficient way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, it is really the only log message. I recognize this may be inefficient - this is just one iteration (pure SQL also did not work). The number of pieces will vary as it is a user-based app. I have not tried it with the production database, why would this matter?

Comment: If the bug arises from something having to do with the number of objects or so forth. When I'm debugging something like this, I like to try and reduce the number of differences between my dev environment and production.

Comment: okay - I see. By full copy, do you mean seed the heroku database with the contents of my rails database or is there another way?

Comment: I mean copy the database from Heroku into your local Postgres instance. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export.